# Passing matrix parameter in Postman

Tags: api, rest, url, postman, query-string

i'm trying to test some REST's API with Postman. When I click on `Params` button and enter a `key` and `value` my URL is something like `www.example\rest\api?key=value`, my API does not support query parameters, is there any way to pass like a matrix parameter something like `www.example\rest\api;key=value` or should I enter manually in URL area?

Answer (score 0):

If your API expect the input as part of the request body you should pass the keys/values using the **form-data** button in Postman.